# How to fetch a query to get the following data?

Tags: sql

List the names and designation of those employees whose salary is greater than 2000 and address is US.

Comment: If you had provided sample data and some more detail, this would have been a workable question.  But just giving us a one sentence requirement is not going to get much attention.

Comment: What's your schema like, what's your data like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your lucky I had my coffee this morning...

```
select name, designation from employees where salary > 2000 and country = 'US';
```

Comment: If you need coffee to write that query, then something is wrong with you :-P

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen More of being in a good mood and not down voting into oblivion

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen And I Thank You kind sir, was fully expecting the onslaught of the downvoters.  Good thing its still the weekend here.